# 2-D arrays and functions

Tags: c

The following code is not working if you compile it as it is, but when you replace `*(p+i*C+j)` with `(*p+i*C+j)`, it works. Can anybody help me in understanding why, as the method which I have learnt to the same function is already in the code? Also, I have written other codes which have the same syntax and work perfectly. I don't know why this one isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void disp(int *p[][20],int R,int C)//Method 1
{int i,j;
 printf("Elements are(disp):\n");
 for(i=0;i<R;i++)
 {for(j=0;j<C;j++)
  {printf("%d ",p[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 } 
}
void disp1(int *p,int R,int C)//Method 2
{int i,j;
 printf("Elements are(disp1):\n");
 for(i=0;i<R;i++)
 {for(j=0;j<C;j++)
  {printf("%d ",*(p+i*C+j));
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}
int main()
{int i,j,R,C,a[20][20];
 printf("Enter R and C");
 scanf("%d %d",&R,&C);
 printf("\nEnter the elements:");
 for(i=0;i<R;i++)
 {for(j=0;j<C;j++)
  {scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
  }
 }
 disp(a,R,C);
 printf("\n\n");
 disp1(a,R,C);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: pay attention to compiler messages, you should get some for the line `disp1(a,R,C);`

Answer (score 1):

This prototype is wrong:

```
void disp(int *p[][20],int R,int C)
```

here `p` is a 2D array of pointers to `int`. The `*` binds to the left.

you want

```
void disp(int p[20][20],int R,int C)
```

which is internally rewritten to be the same as

```
void disp(int (*p)[20],int R,int C)
```

But you should really stick to the version with the `[20][20]` which makes your intentions clear.